# Which id is relabel for in app purchase record at developer server for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on in app purchase app and in my in app purchase i am posting users device ValidationID for my own information (UDID is deprecated from IOS6 so validation id).
But in some case validationID retuns 00000.0000.000000 ( when you update your ipad or iphone from 5.1 to 6.1 direct) at that time ios having this issue.[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12608155/1688521)

I am using these id to have log store in my server but in this case every-time device returns 00000 So which ID should i use int this case??
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never identify a device, but user. So you can use any unique ID of the device.
Read by blog post: "[Deprecating uniqueIdentifier is a good thing](http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/uniqueidentifier-deprecated-is-a-good-thing/)" why you should never use a device identifier.

If you are using InApp purchases the user should have to option to restore there purchases. `StoreKit` has an option to allow a user to restore any previous purchases.

Comment: @rckones yes i have done restoration according to apple sends me back all product list and transaction receipt and than i send that to my own server for validation...but i just need device ID for my LOG (just to store information on my server side ..as client need to know how many device using their app and how many videos are purchased by an avarage user ..)

Comment: This is no longer possible, you might use the application, vendor or advertisement id for this. But these can be reset by the user. So you can say with a 100% that the id will be unique device, nice some device will have changed there id.