# identifierForVendor behavior in debug

Tags: ios

In Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) for `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]`, they state:

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device.

I take this to mean that if I have more than one app from me on a device, any of those apps should get the same value for this property across reinstalls of the app.  But I'm not seeing that in debugging.  I have a device with two different apps from me on it.  I note the value in one of the apps, remove it, then reinstall it, and note a different value.  Could this be because I'm debugging, or because there's something else going on?  Can anyone confirm that this API does what it says it will?  I've found at least [one other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605257/the-advertisingidentifier-and-identifierforvendor-return-00000000-0000-0000-000) about problems here.

Answer (score 1):

Further along in the same documentation:

> The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

From what I understand you install and app, remove it and reinstall it thus having deleted all the apps for a brief period of time which leads to a new identifier upon the next install.

Comment: But I have more than one app from me on the device.  So I'm never getting into a state where there are no apps from me on the device.  Therefore it should stay the same, should it not?

Comment: What iOS version are you testing? Today, after a prolonged testing period, I've come to a conclusion that identifierForVendor is unstable for all versions prior to 6.1.3. Install the latest iOS version and you should be fine.