# identifierForVendor property returning undefined for iOS

Tags: cordova, mobile, plugins, uniqueidentifier, ios9.2

We are getting identifierForVendor value as undefined. iOS app is Compiled using iOS9.2 and Corodva 5.3.1. Any possible reasons? App Used to work fine till last release.

Comment: You need to show the code you are using.

Comment: Added code in the answer

Comment: Um, ok, I don't quite get it, but if you added it as an answer, then you must be all set.

Comment: +(NSString*)uniqueIDForDevice
{
    NSString* uniqueIdentifier = nil;
    if( [UIDevice instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)] ) {
        // >=iOS 7
        uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    }
    else {  //<=iOS6, Use UDID of Device
        CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        //uniqueIdentifier = ( NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);- for non- ARC
        uniqueIdentifier = ( NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid));// for ARC
        CFRelease(uuid);
    }
    return uniqueIdentifier;

}

Comment: So it sounds like you are trying to build a plugin - is that right?

Comment: I am using CDVDevice.m ..in that I have added a method to get a unique Id for a device

Basically org.apache.cordova.device plugin

Comment: If you modified the plugin then be sure you are rebuilding the code. You may also need to update the JS code.

Comment: Yes done with it..Have rebuilt the code and JS I need to manually update or it will be generated when I do 'cordova build'... It has worked fine for last two releases and giving issue now...

Answer (score 1):

Just use the latest version of `cordova-plugin-device`

`device.uuid` returns the `identifierForVendor` now

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device

Comment: Thanks will try this..Any idea its changed in which version? and identifierForVendor is deprecated now?

Comment: Is there any chnace of getting value of uuid as 0 during development?

Comment: It seems that there is a bug and in some devices can return 0000... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605257/the-advertisingidentifier-and-identifierforvendor-return-00000000-0000-0000-000/12608155

Comment: Yes but that thread is of 2012.. Should be fixed by now right..I have implemented new version of device plugin as suggested by you.. and getting 0 as the uuid now..

Comment: Is it possible that in development build I am getting it as 0 and after releasing to app store will get proper value?

Comment: I get values even with development build, so it might not be fixed

Comment: Oh can u pls suggest how I can test this?

Comment: are you getting 0 or 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000? In which ios version do you get it?

Comment: I am getting 0. iOS version is 9.2.1

Comment: That's really strange. I've heard about the 000000..., but never about just 0. I've tested on a device with iOS 9.2.1 and I got the right identifier. Are you using your paid developer account? or a free account?

Comment: It's paid developer account.. I am exporting the IPA and checking on iphone.. Checked in iPad as well.. I am getting 0.. Any other compatibility I might have to check?

Comment: I don't know what else to check. I've checked on my app and all the users have returned a valide identifier on production, but I've never received 0 while developing. BTW, I'm adding a link to the cordova JIRA issue so if someone else have this issue can provide data there https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10415

Comment: I recreated the project and added the latest version of device plugin. Now in uuid I am getting the identifierForVendor. Thanks @jcesarmobile .

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I'm closing the jira issue.